# Database connections and functions?

Tags: php, mysql, function

I'm new to using functions, so - no judgements please ;).

Let's say I have a function `add_to_x()` in `function.php` which within performs a `mysql_query()`. This function is included, (`include "function.php";`), into `script.php`, and called mid-way through that script. At the top of `function.php` I establish a database connection, closing it at the end.

Would this be passed through by default to the function `add_to_x()` or would I need to establish and close a connection within `add_to_x()` itself?

---

**For illustration and good measure:**

*Contents of script.php*

```
include "function.php";
// Do something
add_to_x($arg1, $arg2);
// Do something else
```

*Contents of function.php*

```
include "db_conn.php";
$conn = mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass); mysql_select_db($db_name);

function add_to_x($arg1, $arg2) {
    // Do something
    $query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE x = '$arg1'";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
}

mysql_close($conn);
```

***Would that work? Or would I need to do something like this:***

```
function add_to_x($arg1, $arg2) {
    include "db_conn.php";
    $conn = mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass); mysql_select_db($db_name);
    // Do something
    $query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE x = '$arg1'";
    $result = mysql_query($query)
    mysql_close($conn);
}
```

It might look like a rather stupid question, but I'm not sure of the scope of connections/functions. I feel that perhaps the second example would be better practice even if the first would work?

Any comments, advice, answers would be greatly appreciated! (I realize I've made this question a bit messy, but I hope the illustration code helps, and of course, if you need further clarification please do ask for it)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open the database connection in the file that defines your functions, as you are doing. But closing it at the end of `function.php` is *not* what you want to do - by doing this you are closing the connection before it is ever used.

You would either call `mysql_close()` at the very end of your main script (after all calls to functions that require the connection), or not at all (the resource will be implicitly closed/freed when the script finishes).

Comment: Ah, that makes a lot more sense. Would I need to open it within the file `function.php` (the file that defines the functions) and close it in `script.php` (the file that called them) that or could I just open the connection within `script.php` anytime before the function `add_to_x()` is called and close it at the end? Or would it need to be opened before `include "function.php"`?

Comment: It only needs to be opened before you use it - it doesn't matter where. So as long as it has been opened before a call to `add_to_x()`, it doesn't matter in which file or at what stage it was opened.

Answer (score 1):

Any code that's in the global scope of `function.php` (ie not inside a function), will be executed when you include the script. So in the code you posted, the `$conn` will no longer be open in your `add_to_x()`.

Comment: What about if the connection was opened in `script.php` the function `add_to_x()`called (minus the connection inside/outside, so just the query) and then closed after the function is run?

Comment: That will work -- provided you access the variable using the `global` keyword, as jancha said in his answer.

Comment: @Rijk while you are technically correct (the best kind of correct) it should be noted that this is not stricly required if you are only dealing with one database connection, since MySQL will always use the last used connection resource if you don't specify one. This works regardless of variable scope.

Answer (score 1):

Few things to explain:
1) If you have `$conn` defined in global scope, you can access it from any function using keyword `global` e.g.

```
function add_to_x(){
    global $conn;
}
```

2) you can use mysql queries in your functions even if connection is made "outside", as mysql will use last opened connector, unless other specified

summing up, first of your example should work (did not check parsing etc).